# Изменение src картинки через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <img src="./img/Karachaevsk.jpg" alt="Карачаевск" class="elements__photo">
    <div class="elements__group">
        <h2 class="elements__title">Карачаевск</h2>
        <img src="./img/like.svg" alt="Лайк" class="elements__like">
    </div>
</div>
```

Добрый день подскажите как реализовать через JS что бы при клике на картинку src=./img/like.svg менялся у нее путь на src=./img/blacklike.svg - Проще говоря с белого сердце на черное и обратно. Из идей функция которая работает по клику в бесконечном цикле. К сожалению пока других путей не знаю да и этот не особо понимаю(

Answer (score 5):

Это для одного лайка:

```js
document.querySelector('.elements__like').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  let hasLike = this.classList.toggle('liked');
  this.src = hasLike ? './img/blacklike.svg' : './img/like.svg';
});
```

```html
<img src="./img/Karachaevsk.jpg" alt="Карачаевск" class="elements__photo">
<div class="elements__group">
    <h2 class="elements__title">Карачаевск</h2>
    <img src="./img/like.svg" alt="Лайк" class="elements__like">
</div>
```

А это для нескольких:

```js
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.elements__like') ).forEach( element => {
  element.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    let hasLike = this.classList.toggle('liked');
    this.src = hasLike ? './img/blacklike.svg' : './img/like.svg';
  });
});
```

```html
<img src="./img/Karachaevsk.jpg" alt="Карачаевск" class="elements__photo">
<div class="elements__group">
    <h2 class="elements__title">Карачаевск</h2>
    <img src="./img/like.svg" alt="Лайк" class="elements__like">
</div>

<img src="./img/Drugoi.jpg" alt="Другой город" class="elements__photo">
<div class="elements__group">
    <h2 class="elements__title">Другой город</h2>
    <img src="./img/like.svg" alt="Лайк" class="elements__like">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Pavel а как реализовать Если несколько "лайков" с одним и тем же классом. Сейчас получается что только на 1 элемент работает данная функция, но у меня их 9) Как обобщить? )

Comment: @maksimkhromov95 Дописал пример

Comment: спасибо огромное все отлично работает.
Не могли бы подсказать как сделать на таком примере для всех элементов: 
`
const switchLike = document.querySelector('.elements__like');
switchLike.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const image = switchLike.getAttribute('src')
        if (image === './img/like.svg') {
            switchLike.removeAttribute('src');
            switchLike.setAttribute('src', './img/blacklike.svg');
        } else {
            switchLike.removeAttribute('src');
            switchLike.setAttribute('src', './img/like.svg');
        }
})
`

Comment: @maksimkhromov95 зачем? спросите того кто это пишет :) . Атрибут src здесь ни к чему, можно просто `switchLike.src` писать.

Comment: @maksimkhromov95 Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.